# Feeding a 2D image to a TensorFlow CNN for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Thanks for helping with this. I'm trying to train a convolutional neural network to predict a binary aspect of my system using TensorFlow. I have roughly 1000 ndarrays, of size 400x400x3, holding floats. This is similar (I think) to an RGB image; the three aspects of my image aren't colour but the outputs of three different functions, but that's not material here. Each of these ndarrays is associated with a binary label-- either 0 or 1. I'm new to TensorFlow though reasonably solid on principles of machine learning, so would really appreciate guidance on decoding errors. I think the way I've arranged layers is weird, but I've tried to follow the tutorial pretty closely so I don't know why.

My code is as follows:

```
no_of_samples = 1035
train_batches = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 23
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 50

data, labels = np.load("total_image_data.npy", allow_pickle=True), np.load("labels.npy", allow_pickle=True)

#divide into test and train sets

train_indices = np.random.choice([i for i in range(no_of_samples)], size=train_batches*BATCH_SIZE)
test_indices = [i for i in range(no_of_samples) if i not in train_indices]

data_train, labels_train = [data[i] for i in train_indices], [labels[i] for i in train_indices]
data_test, labels_test = [data[i] for i in test_indices], [labels[i] for i in test_indices]

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_train, labels_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data_test, labels_test))

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)



model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(200, 5, strides=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 400, 400, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(100, 5, strides=2, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 5, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 2, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 2, activation="relu"),
    
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(),

    # Finally, we add a classification layer.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])

model.fit(labels_train, data_train, epochs=10, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

model.evaluate(labels_test, data_test)
```

And the error I get when I run it is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 36, in <module>
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  File "/local/**/ac3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 530, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/local/**/ac3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/local/**/ac3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 213, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 23, 58, 58, 25)
```

Any help decoding this would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: new and exciting errors! After some help from some generous members of the community my code now looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

no_of_samples = 1035
BATCH_SIZE = 16
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 50

data, labels = np.load("total_image_data.npy", allow_pickle=True), np.load("labels.npy", allow_pickle=True)

print(np.shape(data)) ##this outputs (1035, 400, 400, 3)
print(np.shape(labels)) ##this outputs (1035, )



#divide into test and train sets


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels)).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
test_dataset = dataset.take(100).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_dataset = dataset.skip(100).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(200, 5, strides=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(400, 400, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(100, 5, strides=2, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 5, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 2, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 2, activation="relu"),
    
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(),

    # Finally, we add a classification layer.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

print('Labels shape -->',labels.shape)
print('Labels -->', labels)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10)
model.evaluate(test_dataset)
```

This compiles and runs fine, but reports a loss of nan and an unchanging accuracy across epochs of 58% (the baseline prevalence of the thing I'm looking for is 38%). Again, I throw myself upon your mercy.

Comment: You must not put the BATCH_SIZE in your input definition:
`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(200, 5, strides=3, activation='relu', input_shape=( 400, 400, 3))`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change a few things: the input shape to your model does not need the `batch_size`, it will be inferred during training. Change it to `(400, 400, 3)`. Second, if you are working with binary labels, you need to change your loss function to `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy` and your metric to `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy` or simply `accuracy`. Furthermore, your output layer should have one output node instead of two: `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)`

Here is a running example based on your code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

no_of_samples = 250
BATCH_SIZE = 16
SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE = 50

data, labels = np.random.random((no_of_samples, 400, 400, 3)), np.random.randint(2, size=no_of_samples)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels)).shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER_SIZE)
test_dataset = dataset.take(50).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
train_dataset = dataset.skip(50).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(200, 5, strides=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(400, 400, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(100, 5, strides=2, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 5, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(50, 2, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(25, 2, activation="relu"),
    
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(),

    # Finally, we add a classification layer.
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=test_dataset)
```

```
print('Labels shape -->',labels.shape)
print('Labels -->', labels)
Labels shape --> (250,)
Labels --> [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I tried running your code on my data, and it generated the following error ```TypeError: Failed to convert elements of <keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy object at 0x7f819052d3a0> to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.``` There are only 2 things I can think of causing this: the fact that my labels are integers (?) or something to do with my input data, though yours are also ndarrays of the same shape. Is this obvious to you? Again, many thanks.

Comment: Check if your labels look like the labels in my answer. I posted them at the bottom.

Comment: They do! It seems to be running now that I've fixed the metrics-- can't tell you how grateful I am. The only thing I slightly worry about is that I'm watching it run and it says 'loss=nan'- should I be worried about that? The accuracy's changing...

Comment: Yeah, the loss should not be nan. If you copied the whole code that I posted and just adapted the data preprocessing part to fit your data then it must be something wrong with your data, because the model is running perfectly fine with dummy data.  It’s hard to say what is the cause without seeing everything. Maybe update your question with the code you are currently using

Comment: @JoannaLupin Did  you fix your issue?

Comment: I don't think so-- I just went back and checked the output when I left it to run, and the loss is still nan at every epoch. I'll take another look at my input data and update my question with code-- thanks so much.

Comment: Did you make sure that you set `from_logits=True` in your loss function? `              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`. Carefully review the code in my answer. Also, you might want to normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

When the loss goes to nan the easiest explanation is that you are having either exploding or vanishing gradients. Try using gradient clipping (either by value or by norm) on your optimizer, that basically does not allow the gradients to go above or beyond a certain value.

This also can affect the performance of the network but is always better than a loss of nan.

With your current code, the implementation would look like this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(clipvalue=0.5),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The value is just an example, if it works, try tweaking it a bit.

Comment: Interestingly, that _doesn't_ work. Is there anything else that might be doing it? Is my input weird? Very grateful again.

Comment: I just realized, your output layer does not have an explicitly stated activation function and so it defaults to Linear. For binary classification the recommended is Sigmoid. `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")` 
I ran it on my machine, the loss and accuracy get unstuck

Comment: Or..as already, suggested...use the `from_logits=True` of your loss function and leave the loss function linear.